# Having trouble with dataDetectorTypes in iOS 10.0.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, datadetectortypes

In iOS below 10 my code works normally:

[image: figure 1]

But when i run the same code in iOS 10.0.2 the result becomes like this:

[image: figure 2]

You can see that the color highlighted blue only the first number and the next have an underline and not blue colored.

So, the problem is that in iOS 10.0.2 the highlight is not all blue same as iOS that below than 10. I want it to be all highlight blue same the first picture.

The link still works if i clicked on it, it just highlights differently.

I cant seem to find what cause it to be like this on iOS 10.0.2

Here's the function that i wrote inside a class of UITableViewCell:

```
func setCellDescriptionTextView(description: String, isDetectForLink: Bool) {
    self.descriptionTextView.setLineSpacingText(description)
    self.descriptionTextView.dataDetectorTypes = isDetectForLink ? [.PhoneNumber, .Link] : .None
}
```

Comment: @MartinR ok I added some of the code Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce with this string. Is this the full string or do you have some text before/after? Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasDeniau the full string contain normal string, a phone number, and an email address. Ok I will try sent to apple. Thanks

Comment: OK the email address triggers a signature detection which is displayed in grey now instead of blue. I do not think there's anything you can do about this unfortunately.

Comment: I think so too. I already sent bug report to apple so hopefully they will fix this.

Comment: Any news about this?